# authentication page error in visual studio for ASP.net Core project

Tags: c#

i have a problem. i want to create a ASP.Net Core project .i want to select a API, Web or Empty project but this authentication page is not open [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHjV8.png)

Comment: Please be a bit more precise and please convey the error clearly.

Comment: Please provide more information, which authentication page is not open?